# SSL Errors when implementing an SSL tunnelling

Tags: sockets, ssl, proxy, tunnel

I'm implementing an SSL tunnelling proxy, just like what Squid proxy's CONNECT tunnel provides

However, I observed that sometimes the SSL connections go through me return SSL Errors.Those errors are: invalid TLS padding, bad record MAC...

My proxy is simple, just read() from downstream socket then write() to upstream socket. (I also implemented data buffering when one of those pair sockets is not writable)

Hope you can help me with this

Edited: Mine is just a tunnel forwarding proxy, I do not intercept the SSL connection between client and server. Just read() then write()

Comment: Which are the OpenSSL versions that you're using at both ends (that fail to communicate)? (`${PATH_TO_YOUR_OPENSSL}/openssl version -a`) Can you post the (client and server) code responsible with SSL connection setup? There are a bunch of reasons for this error, I have encountered it in the past but i want to have all the details before posting an answer. Do you by any chance enable FIPS at one connection endpoint?

Comment: Thanks for comment CristiFati. I edited my post to add more details. My program works very simply, just forward data it read() from a socket to another by write() (Don't care what in data). So it has no SSL setup in there

Comment: Got it, then how do you setup your (downstream and upstream) sockets? where do you connect them? Most likely this is the cause.

Comment: The upstream one is connected to destination server. Then I forward data received on socket to its pair one. Actually the program runs well if I try smth like wget. But it goes problem when I use browser, which creates many sockets at same time. Some will fall in to that SSL error, some will be timed out because nothing else transfer between them after a while

Comment: ok, no code... most likely your wget somehow ignores certs(due to arguments passed?). Note that when a SSL connection takes place, the endpoints (client and server) negotiate their ciphers; if they have (at least) one cipher in common the communication can go on, otherwise a connection error is returned. A simple socket tunneling cannot be done between 2 remote endpoints that use SSL(or can be but the endpoints must have similar SSL settings); you should connect/(accept connections) to/(from) each, and decrypt/encrypt messages from/to accepted forms.

Comment: When I use browser, just a few connection get caught in those problems. Otherwise they are good to process. I forward any data I read() so endpoints get extractly what other send. Could you tell me more about those SSL settings you mentioned?

Comment: Here are a couple of links: http://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/how-does-ssl-work-what-ssl-handshake, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257591. As seen, client and server must agree on a cipher (they'll both use when sending/receiving).